# not able to establish socket connection with server running on different port based on path/endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io

client --

```
var socket = io(
{
  transports : ['polling'],
  path : '/mysocket'
});
```

server--

```
io = require('socket.io')(server,{
   path : '/mysocket'
});
```

nginx --

```
location /socket/ {
  proxy_pass http://example.com:3005
}
```

https://example.com is running on two ports 3003 & 3005 all endpoints are connected to 3003 and my end point is connected to 3005 where my socket connections will be done,but the the socket is not connecting to 3005 instead it is connecting to 3003.

Comment: You should provide more information about your server code.
Are you using express ? have you make express listen on both ports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was nginx where i was missing i need to add

```
location /socket/ {
  proxy_http_version 1.1
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_pass http://example.com:3005;
}
```

this solved my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).